# WIX: Prevent removing pre-existing files during uninstall

Tags: installation, wix, uninstallation, wix3.6

The WIX installer I'm writing needs to install several operating system files in system folder. The program I'm writing this installer for is an old program... probably 10 years. I don't want it to replace any preexisting OS files on the user's machine. To resolve this, I figured I could use "NeverOverwrite="yes"

My problem is during the uninstall. I want the installer to ONLY uninstall the files it added. I don't want it to uninstall any pre-exisitng OS files the user already had.

Thank you

Comment: The installer should only delete the files in the components its has installed. Is the installer deleting the files that were already on the system?

Comment: It is. It's being quite strange. Another thing it's doing... on one of the components I had added NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes". That was working as expected, it did not remove the file during uninstall or overwrite during install. However, I removed Permanent="yes", built the installer again and it's still not removing the file during uninstall even though i removed that code. I tried cleaning the soln and rebuilding... still no good. Other changes i make to the code still appear tho

Comment: Have you followed a verbose log? I would take BryanJ's advice and make them permanent so that they dont get uninstalled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installer should not delete files that it did not install (as Natalie commented), unless you specifically tell it to.

That said, when I need to install files directly to the system folder, I mark them as permanent so they never get uninstalled. Usually it's a Mircrosoft control or some OS file for which I don't have a separate redistributable installer, but if I had I wouldn't uninstall anyway.

Comment: Yeah I was going to do that. The only problem is there are about 70 os files it's installing. I don't want it to leave a large amount of files that the user doesn't need when they uninstall. I suppose tho permanent would be the only way?

Comment: Like Natalie suggested, you could do a verbose log and see exactly what is going on. I'm guessing though, you'll have to just mark them as permanent. One other area to look into is setting SharedDllRefCount="yes" on the component of each file. This may not actually help your situation, if the registry entries created by setting that attribute don't already exist, but it's a way to keep track of shared files. I normally don't like doing this though, as the reference count in the registry can easily get screwed up.

Comment: Alright thank you guys! I'm new to wix... how do i get the verbose? Do I just run msiexec.exe /i MyInstaller.msi /Lv* LogFile.txt or is there anything else i need to do

Comment: That is correct, although you can also add 'x' to get extra debugging information, ex: "/lvx* LogFile.txt". Out of habit I list everything "/lvoicewarmupx LogFile.txt" but that is the same thing.